# WebStorm fonts extremely thin

Tags: fonts, ide, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I am using WebStorm on Windows. I get my fonts thinner than usual. I wonder if there is a way to fix it. Here are some comparison between WebStorm and Sublime text 3.

---

[image]

**Hack** in **WebStorm**, which has thinner fonts.

---

[image]

**Hack** in **Sublime Text 3**, which gets much better fonts rendering.

---

[image]

**Consolas** in **WebStorm**, again, it is thinner than usual.

---

[image]

**Consolas** in **Sublime Text 3**, it is much better.

---

I know, **Hack** in WebStorm looks really like **Consolas** in it, but I am sure the first one is **Hack** and the second one is **Consolas**.

What I want, is a way to get the fonts in WebStorm behave like normal.

Comment: `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behaviour | Appearance --> Antialiasing` -- try different options there. For some it helps. Also -- what Java do you use (from `About` screen)?.

Comment: @LazyOne This does not work at all. **Subpixel* looks same as **grayscale**, **Not Antialiasing** makes it even worse. I am using: JRE: 1.8.0_76-release-b216 x86, JVM: OpenJDK Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

Comment: No other ideas from me then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YES! I solved this problem! So what you need to do is to install an application named **MacType**. Then, use the preset **default.ini**. Here you go.

[image: Result]

I spend like 5+ hours on this stupid problem today. I am so excited now. I hope it helped. :)

Comment: This looks super sketchy.

Comment: @JarrodW.When I had the problem, I didn't know Imgur existed. I just googled the some random free image hosting website and post my screenshot there. I didn't have enough reputation to upload directly to Stack Overflow either.